# If item is selected in ListView JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

If I have a list and a button . And I want that button disabled until an item from that list has been selected , what is the best method to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ListView`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) has a property named [`selectionModel`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#selectionModelProperty) which holds a [`MultipleSelectionModel`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/MultipleSelectionModel.html) object. This selection model has properties/lists that represents what items are selected, if any. There are two modes to this selection model:

1. `SINGLE`: Only one item can be selected at a time.
2. `MULTIPLE`: Any number of items can be selected at a time.

It might matter what selection mode you're using, but I'm not positive. For single-selection, I'd observe the `selectedItem` or `selectedIndex` property. For multi-selection, I'd observe the `selectedItems` or `selectedIndices` `ObservableList`. (*Note: While I'm not positive, I'd expect either method to work regardless of the selection mode*)

```
// single selection mode
button.disableProperty()
        .bind(listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());

// multiple selection mode
button.disableProperty()
        .bind(Bindings.isEmpty(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));
```

The first option uses the [`isNull`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/ObjectExpression.html#isNull()) method of the `selectedItem` property. The method returns a `BooleanBinding` which binds the `disable` property of the `Button`.

The second option uses [`Bindings.isEmpty`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#isEmpty(javafx.collections.ObservableList)) which creates a `BooleanBinding` that will be `true` when the `ObservableList` is empty. Like the first option, the `disable` property is bound to this `BooleanBinding`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `isNull` to create a `BooleanBinding` based on the `selectedItem` property of the selection model. Use this to bind the `disable` property of the button:

```
button.disableProperty().bind(listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());
```